# How to make a WishedProduct Widget using FirebaseFirestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a product display app.
I'm going to create a "Wish List" widget that brings up the product that the user picked as 'wish item'.

[image: I structured the data by creating a collection ('Wish') in Doc ('User A') of the Collection ('User') and storing the wish product as a doc. (as shown in picture 1)]

I structured it as shown in picture 1.
And to create a widget,
I get all the documents of the collection('wish') of doc('User A').
And with their String values(product name) of the doc,
Get the product data from the collection ('Product') using Query.

The product collection is shown in the picture below.

[image: I will make ListView widget of the wish product.]

Is there a more efficient way?
I thought it might be easier to change the data structure.
However, even if I create a new Collection('Wish'), at the same level as Collection('Product'), and put the product's name and user's e-mail in it,
I need to focus on the 'Product' collection with the 'Product name'.
Because I have to use the price, brand, name of product, in Collection('Product').

Is there any other efficient way I'm missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the product name in string you can use `reference` type to store direct reference of the document inside other document.

Example code

```
DocumentReference ref = db.collection('products').doc('product-document-id');
Map<String,dynamic> data = {
        'name' : 'Product A',
         'product_ref' : ref,  // Product document Reference 
        };
db.collection("users")
   .doc("user-id")
   .collection("wish")
   .doc("your_product_name")
   .set(data);
```

This will add the wish product with dynamic id.
Now you can directly read the document using the `product_ref`. You can use something like this

```
final docRef = db.collection("users")
   .doc("user-id")
   .collection("wish").doc("your_product_name");
final docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
if (docSnapshot.exists) {
   final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
   var productRef = data?['product_ref'];

   productRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
         // you will get your product here
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: I realized i don't know well about firebasefirestore itself. veryvery thank you, HAPPY NEW YEAR!! :)

Comment: You are welcome, and a happy new year to you too. :)